# Extract number within square brackets from string

Tags: javascript, regex

using JavaScript and Regular Expressions, how can I get the first match of a number (positive or negative) within square brackets.

For example, how can I extract the number 232 in the following text:
*"Hello this is a number [232]"*

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and we'll help you from there.

Comment: (?<=\[)\d+(?=\]) try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capture group to pull the number out with something like:

```js
let s = "Hello this is a number [232]"
let t =  "Hello [-100] this is a number "
let u =  "Hello [-232a] this [121] is a number " // doesn't match 232a


let rx = /\[(-?\d+)\]/

console.log(s.match(rx)[1])
console.log(t.match(rx)[1])
console.log(u.match(rx)[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const patter = /(?!\[)-?\d+(?=\])/g;
// will return only number without []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for capturing the same.

```js
// Capture the number(negative, integer or decimal)
// which is prefixed by '[' and and suffixed by ']'
const pattern = /(?<=\[)-?\d+(\.\d+)?(?=\])/

console.log('Hello [-123] testing =>', 'Hello [-123] testing'.match(pattern)[0]);
console.log('Hello [-123.12] testing =>', 'Hello [-123.12] testing'.match(pattern)[0]);
console.log('Hello [123] testing =>', 'Hello [123] testing'.match(pattern)[0]);
console.log('Hello [123.123] testing =>', 'Hello [123.123] testing'.match(pattern)[0]);
```